# Configuring PCL project with a JSON file

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, portable-class-library

I'm currently designing a cross-plateform application in Visual Studio 2013 using a Portable Class Library.

At startup, I want to have a certain object, created by deserializing a JSON file. This object will be used to configure certain resources in my project (e.g. certain button names, etc.).
I know how to parse the JSON file using Json.NET and to create the wanted object.

What I don't know is how to use it, and especially, where must it be generated? I don't think this JSON reading part could (and should) be added to the PCL, for the file reading part at least.

Thanks in advance (I hope this isn't a duplicate!)

Comment: [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) is available as a Portable Class Library, although I do not know which platforms the PCL version target. Maybe you can use this library?

Comment: Yes, Json.NET is available and could be used for parsing the Json object.The main problem here is reading the file containing the Json object: it cannot be done in the PCL. But that is ok, I just want to read it once, and then build the project using the read values somehow... I hope I was clear

Comment: OK, I (think I) understand. There is also a PCL project for portable file I/O, [PCL Storage](https://pclstorage.codeplex.com/). You could consider using (PCL) *Json.NET* and *PCL Storage* in combination in your PCL project.

Comment: thanks @AndersGustafsson, PCL Storage sound interesting, I'll have a look :)